# System tray application Linux Qt/C++

Tags: c++, linux, qt, system-tray, trayicon

I'm writing an application in ***C++*** with ***Qt*** that utilizes the ***system tray***.

I have implemented the ***system tray*** using a `QSystemTrayIcon` class as shown in the examples, but it doesn't have the same behavior as other ***system tray icons*** that are present on my computer.

For instance, I have Spotify installed on Ubuntu 12.04 and it shows a ***system tray icon*** with a ***drop down menu***. With my application, it shows a ***system tray icon*** with a ***context menu***, meaning you have to right click it to make the menu active.

With Spotify, all that needs to be done is to ***click*** on the icon and the menu will show.

What can I do to get native system tray icons in Ubuntu?

I'm fine with using specific code for `X11/Linux` and not the built-in Qt functions.

Here's my code:

```cpp
void MainWindow::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event)
{
    if (trayIcon->isVisible()) {
        hide();
        event->ignore();
    }
}

void MainWindow::createActions()
{
    restoreAction = new QAction(tr("&Show"), this);
    connect(restoreAction, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(show()));

    quitAction = new QAction(tr("&Exit"), this);
    connect(quitAction, SIGNAL(triggered()), qApp, SLOT(quit()));
}

void MainWindow::createTrayIcon()
{
    trayIconMenu = new QMenu(this);
    accountsMenu = trayIconMenu->addMenu(tr("Accounts"));
    trayIconMenu->addSeparator();
    trayIconMenu->addAction(restoreAction);
    trayIconMenu->addSeparator();
    trayIconMenu->addAction(quitAction);

    trayIcon = new QSystemTrayIcon(this);
    trayIcon->setContextMenu(trayIconMenu);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue when we deployed our product (built using Qt) on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

We use the `qt.conf` way of deployment.
After a lot of hunting and going through the source on `sni-qt` I found that plugins need to be properly found out. So I created and copied the plugins from our build environment to the plugins directory relative to my application path mentioned in `qt.conf` against the `'Plugins = '` entry.

We also made sure that `sni-qt` is up-to-date and installed on the deployed Ubuntu 12.04 machine.

The menus appeared as they appear for other tray applications.

You can copy plugins from `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt4/plugins/` on a `32 bit` machine or its equivalent path on `64 bit` machine.

For this problem, plugin under `systemtrayicon` is the required one.

HTH.

Answer (score 5):

Try to drop down menu from [activated](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qsystemtrayicon.html#activated) signal of QSystemTrayIcon.

```
void Window::iconActivated(QSystemTrayIcon::ActivationReason reason)
 {
     switch (reason) {
         case QSystemTrayIcon::Trigger:
             // show your menu here
     }
 }
```

Comment: This will show the menu, but it only shows a context menu and I want to have it show a non-context menu. I think it might have something to do with Unity, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: I will mark your answer as the correct answer, but I would still like to know how to tie into Ubuntu's global menu system. Qt 4.8.1 doesn't seem to use the global menu system by default and I can't find the setting to enable it in builds.

Comment: What do you mean by 'global menu system'? Menu which usually at the top left cornrt of window which in ubuntu at the top of the screen?

Comment: I got global menu with QMenuBar in previous version of Qt. I'll check it with Qt 4.8.1. But I don't see how it is connected with tray.

Comment: I got global menu with QMenuBar in Qt 4.8.1. Do you want to show the same menu in menubar and when you click on tray icon?

Comment: Yes, I want to show the same styled menu when you click on the tray icon. I don't want to show the application menu when the tray icon is clicked, but the tray menu. I can try and provide screenshots if that would help explain what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @CameronTinker Screenshots will be helpful.

Comment: I realize that I have not been phrasing this correctly since the initial question. What I want is a Unity indicator instead of a tray indicator. For some reason, I can't get Qt to automatically convert the tray indicator to a Unity indicator. Here's an example of the Unity indicator: http://files.iga-home.net/images/native.png and here's an example of the default tray indicator not converted: http://files.iga-home.net/images/non_native.png According to Qt's forum support, they say you need the package sni-qt to be installed. This is installed with Ubuntu 12.04 by default.